# Maximum call stack size exceeded when trying to update profile data - React Native

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native

I am trying to update the data in my firebase realtime database, but when I try to update it, it keep calling the console in my update function until I got maximum call stack size. I'm not sure why it keep calling the console without stop.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {Button, Gap, Header, Input, Profile} from '../../components';
import {colors, getData} from '../../utils';
import {Fire} from '../../config';
import {getDatabase, ref, set, update, onValue} from 'firebase/database';
import {showMessage} from 'react-native-flash-message';

export default function UpdateProfile({navigation}) {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState({
    fullName: '',
    profession: '',
    email: '',
  });
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    getData('user').then(res => {
      // const data = res;
      // data.photo = {uri: res.photo};
      setProfile({
        fullName: res.data.fullName,
        profession: res.data.profession,
        email: res.data.email,
        photo: res.photo,
      });
    });
  }, []);

  const update = () => {
    console.log('profile: ', profile);
    const db = getDatabase();
    update(ref(db, `users/${profile.uid}/`), {profile})
      .then(res => {
        console.log('success: ', res);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('fak');
        showMessage({
          message: err.message,
          type: 'default',
          backgroundColor: colors.error,
          color: colors.white,
        });
      });
  };

  const changeText = (key, value) => {
    setProfile({
      ...profile,
      [key]: value,
    });
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.page}>
      <Header title="Edit Profile" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
      <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <Profile isRemove photo={profile.photo} />
          <Gap height={26} />
          <Input
            label="Full Name"
            value={profile.fullName}
            onChangeText={value => changeText('fullName', value)}
          />
          <Gap height={24} />
          <Input
            label="Pekerjaan"
            value={profile.profession}
            onChangeText={value => changeText('profession', value)}
          />
          <Gap height={24} />
          <Input label="Email" value={profile.email} disable />
          <Gap height={24} />
          <Input label="Password" value={password} />
          <Gap height={40} />
          <Button title="Save Profile" onPress={update} />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {backgroundColor: colors.white, flex: 1},
  content: {padding: 40, paddingTop: 0},
});
```

[error console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8wDv.png)

Basically the data is called from storedData('user') and put into profile. Then after giving changes to the data, I update the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `update` name!

You defined some actions to get your data like `getData` and `update`.
Also, your handler function name is `update` so when you want to update your profile by pressing the `Save Profile`, it caught in an infinity loop:

You call the `update`, then `console.log` work, then your code call the `update`, then `console.log` then `update` ... until blow the stack:)

So, simply change your handler function name:

```
// rest of the codes ...

const handleUpdateProfile = () => {
  const db = getDatabase();
  update(ref(db, `users/${profile.uid}/`), {profile})
    .then(res => {
      console.log('success: ', res);
     })
    .catch(err => {
      showMessage({
        message: err.message,
        type: 'default',
        backgroundColor: colors.error,
        color: colors.white,
      });
  });
}


// rest of the codes ...

<Button title={"Save Profile"} onPress={handleUpdateProfile} />
```

I suggest you add a prefix for your handler function to determine them easily on your codes.